# Android up navigation issue

Tags: android, navigationbar, back-stack

I'm trying to implement a correct navigation for my app, but I'm failing to understand some of my app's behaviours.

**Navigation wireframe :**
[image: wirefram of the app]

The navigation is quite simple as you can see, and here's what I've done to implement it :

- Simple intents as the one described in the picture
- Setting *Join* as parents activity to *Create*
- Setting *Join* as a **noHistory** activity, so you go to the HOME screen if you go back

But I've encoutered some issues I'd like to solve :

- *Create* has the UP button enabled but I can't reproduce the exact same behaviour when I press the UP or the BACK button on my phone.
  The UP is usually doing the correct work, and I'd like to replicate its behaviour in the instances seen in the wireframe.
- If i go *Create Activity* -> *Home Screen* -> *Create*, and then press BACK **or** UP, I go back to HOME. I'd like the app to go to its parent activity instead.
  Giving the Join Activity to the backstack didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help :) !

Comment: why **noHistory** for JoinActivity ?

Comment: There's an intent in Join that sends you to Main Activity. You should **not** be able to go back to Join if you are in Main by pressing the Back button. That's why I put noHistory, but I may be (probably :p) wrong.

Comment: what is Main Activity ? u did not mentioned above.

Comment: There's just an intent in Join to Main, no big deal. The only rule is you cannot go back in Main. Sorry for the imprecision.

Comment: 2 optional solutions (1) finish JoinActivity if start MainActivity, set noHistory="false"  (2)start new MainActivity if finish CreateActivity, set noHistory="true"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to set `noHistory="true"` for `JoinActivity`.

If set, the activity is not kept in the history stack. As soon as the user navigates away from it, the activity is finished.

So when you press BACK on `CreateActivity`, there's no `JoinActivity` any longer.

There're two optional solution for your case,

1. finish `JoinActivity` if start `MainActivity`, set `noHistory="false"`
2. start new `MainActivity` if finish `CreateActivity`, set `noHistory="true"`

Comment: As I said above, you should not be able to go back to Join if you are in Main by pressing the Back button. That's why I put noHistory.
What should I do ?

Comment: check new answer pls. you may finish JoinActivity before starting MainActivity

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Finishing activities after my intents ended up solving all of my issues.